# Delayed Voicemail Notification

Tags: iphone, voicemail, att

- Country: USA
- Carrier: AT&T
- iPhone: Xs
- iOS Version: 12.4

I’m wondering if this is more carrier-related than phone-related, but on occasion I won’t have a Voicemail notification show up until hours after I miss a call.  This seems to be random as it doesn’t happen for every missed call and doesn’t seem to be exclusive to calls I send to Voicemail or actually miss.

Is there a way to “refresh” my available Voicemail list (as the normal *pull down to refresh* motion doesn’t seem to work) manually?  Has anyone else run into this behavior (and more importantly, fixed it)?

Comment: This is a cell provider problem, most likely.  If you're not seeing any pattern such as it only happens when you're off wifi or notifications are delayed if you're in a specific geographic location, then you'll need to contact AT&T.  I'm not aware of any way to force a refresh of voicemail.

Comment: I've had this same issue with Verizon. Not just hours, sometimes _weeks_.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to update to iOS 12.4.1. It is likely the carrier has a "carrier update" that needs to be applied. You can also try Reset Network Settings to completely rule out the device. After trying these, I would say refer to the carrier.

Comment: Yeah, I figured carrier issue, but you still got to ask.   Was really hoping to see a trick on how to manually refresh my Voicemail notifications list too. Thanks for the answer!